# Want to stream my application view on Apple TV using AirPlay Apl in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, api, airplay, apple-tv

I want to stream my application on APPLE TV using AirPlay API.? How to use that?
Can it work through iPhone and iPad both?
If yesy please share some doc regarding or demo for the same

Comment: Hello, Have you got any success in this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement support for external displays very easily. Here is one blog post about it by Matt Gemmell: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output/

If the user enables AirPlay (by clicking the home button twice and then swiping left to reveal the AirPlay shortcut) with an Apple TV, your app will detect one additional screen, the Apple TV. You can then use the API described in the blog post above to stream your app's view to the Apple TV.

There is no way I know of to add an AirPlay button directly in your app, though.

Comment: But I want to call AirPlay API property on my app i.e. allowsairplay option. On the above blog code they didnt call Airplay option anywhere.Please help me on that prespective.

Comment: Well, that's a property on MPMoviePlayerController. I thought you want to stream your app (your app's view) to the Apple TV and not just a video?

Comment: Yes. Now where we have to call MPMoviePlayerController class on delegate? Because have to show the whole app. Yet I am defining MPMoviePlayerController code on delegate on didFinishLaunchOption am I right? and also please share the code so that I can cross check with mine

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something here. MPMoviePlayerController is for playing a video file only. If you want to mirror your app (not a video, the table views, etc.) to an Apple TV, the user has to enable AirPlay mirroring. If you want to display your app in an external display (TV) over AirPlay, you'll have to use the API described in the blog post.

Comment: and also if I am not writing above blog code on my project Did it affect while connecting to APPLE Tv as I want to connect only to Apple Tv for mirroring.

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: If I wont call above blog api Did it affect while connecting to APPLE TV.

Comment: If you don't implement support for external displays, it won't work, obviously. The user can still mirror your app to the Apple TV, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16000/discussion-between-nishi-and-fabian-kreiser)